# asp.net mvc 4 cache vs entityframework 6 cache

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, caching

A friend and I are developing a web application using `ASP.NET MVC 4` and `EntityFramework 6`. We implemented the Repository Pattern and of course the Entity Framework Context is initialized  and removed each time a user makes a request to access data in the database, so caching system entity Framework first level is not exploited .

I want to implement the second level caching in Entity Framework but he tells that it is not necessary, that we can use the ASP.NET Cache. My question is,

When to use each type of cache?

How fast is each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when to use each type of cache?

There are other performance improvement patterns than writing your own EF provider, which you have to do in order to implement 2nd level cache. My advice (and that's all it is, advice) would be to never implement EF second level cache.

Getting caching right is very difficult, especially cache invalidation.

If your ultimate goal is to deliver web pages quickly, the asp.net cache (or OutputCache) is one way to achieve that. However you then have to choose when to invalidate the cache, which again can be difficult.

> how fast is each other?

Caches usually store data in RAM because that's the fastest way to get data physically. However ultimately speed is going to depend. What cache provider are you using? Is your deployment load-balanced, and if so, do they share the same cache? How do they access it? When you are dealing with the web, you have to consider that the data will be going over the network, so there are all of those latency issues that play a factor too (payload/size, hops, etc.)

If performance is really a problem, you may want to look into patterns that use tools like redis or other nosql providers to store pre-computed denormalized sets of your data for faster access. You can also go outside of EF and craft custom sql for data access points that are giving you particular performance issues.

I really don't think you are going to get any other answers that don't say "it depends" one way or another.

Comment: +1, i know this question is based on many factors, but is always good read other opinions